# How to have optional columns in asp.net list view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I want to have a list view with optional columns by the user. I've tried this code but when there is no sDate column in data table, an error is thrown.

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvDetects">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul class="list zebra">
            <li>
                <span class="DetectsListssDate centerContents">date</span>
            </li>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <%# (Eval("sDate")!=null)?"view something":"nothing" %>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Is it good idea to return only the columns the user selected from database and show them all or to return all columns and then filter column needed?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this in code behind !

```
 protected void lvDetects_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
 {
      System.Data.DataRowView rowView = e.Item.DataItem as System.Data.DataRowView;
      string yourDate = rowView["sDate"].ToString(); // you can check your sDate is null or not

 }
}
```

Comment: So you mean I have to create columns dynamically and let item template be empty?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to just format the date before display.

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="gvLlblOptionMaintenanceDate" runat="server" Text='<%#string.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt}", Eval("MntTimeStamp")) %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="gvLlblOptionMaintenanceDate" runat="server" Text='<%#string.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt}", Eval("MntTimeStamp")) %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>

Comment: @sanjay.arora29 It's not the problem. I dont wnat to have a label when there is no column, and how to format a not existing column?